# How to manage layout and alignment in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, ui5-webcomponents

I recently began coding in React. It is all good, except that i can not find the proper way to manage layouts and alignment in the UI. I am experienced in the UI5 framework where these things come out of the box, but here i can not find such thing-provider library.

I am also using the UI5-WebComponents for React lib, but there are only things like FlexBox and spacing.

Somehow I have avoided using CSS on a large scale, by relying on pre-defined layout components or controls. Is there something similar which I can use in React?

I will be grateful for any help

Comment: It is more a conceptual problem, whether recreating patterns like Master-Detail view is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common adjustment when starting React.  Here is what worked for me.

While in development I put styles in line as follows

```
<MyReactComponent style={{top:'50%',position:'absolute'}} >
...
</MyReactComponent>
```

Once I move to production I can take the styles and move them to .css file

```
.MyReactComponentStyles {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
}
```

then pass the styles on to the component

```
<MyReactComponent className="MyReactComponentStyles" >
...
</MyReactComponent>
```

Comment: I have avoided using CSS on a larger scale by relying on predefined layouts, css classes. Is CSS a must when developing in React?

Comment: Depending on the nature of your project.  For example I work a lot with material UI and there are some projects that do not require any customisation outside of what the framework provides. So `yes` you can avoid CSS.  That being said all frameworks / libs are highly customisable and I find the use of CSS to be indispensable 90%+ of the time.

Comment: I just up voted the question you should have enough points to upvote the answer if you want thanks.